# Full path in terminal prompt and title-bar with modified PS1 in .bashrc

Tags: bash, linux-mint, prompt, gnome-terminal, window-title

I am on several machines running Linux Mint 20.1 "Ulyssa" - Cinnamon (64-bit), [link to web](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=284), with Bash 5.0.17 as my default shell.

Today, I decided I customize my prompt and window title of my terminal emulator, which is GNOME Terminal.

I've known from the past this can be done for example per user in their `.bashrc` file.

As every computer has only one user + `root`, I went this way, I carefully read every line, to be honest, changed comments mostly.

I managed to identify and change colors to my liking. Also, the spacing where I wanted.

---

Relevant PS1 lines:

```sh
# Prompt:
# user @ host : full_path
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u \[\033[00m\]@ \[\033[01;34m\]\h\[\033[00m\] : ${PWD} \$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u @ \h : ${PWD} \$ '
fi

# Set the window title to the same as prompt
case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|rxvt*) PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u @ \h : ${PWD} \a\]$PS1" ;;
               *) ;;
esac
```

---

So, the only thing remaining, which I fail on for hours, is setting the Terminal window title caption, it seemingly works upon launch, but does not change if changing directory. My apologies if it is *messed up*. I just want it to show a full path (no tilde) wherever I am. Thank you.

---

Picture for the words (terminal title-bar caption not updating):

[image: terminal title-bar caption not updating]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reason unknown to me, it was only necessary to escape the `$` (dollar sign) in front of `PWD` in the window title definition on this one line:

```sh
    xterm*|rxvt*) PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u @ \h : \$PWD \a\]$PS1" ;;
```

I tested it somewhat and now preparing to deploy it on all machines.

Comment: That's because the `$PWD` is evaluated when your `.bashrc` is read, so you are actually setting `PS1="... \h : /your/home/` and it never changes after that.

Comment: @terdon Feel free to update the reasoning in my answer. Thank you!